# Maven Category does not appear in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, maven-plugin

I am going to start with GeoTools. Maven in installed correctly as cmd prompt says the version 3.0.4. But in Netbeans 6.5, **Maven Category** does not appear to create a new project. What should I go through now?

Comment: consider upgrading Netbeans. current version is 7.2 has lot of features and inbuilt maven plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link i given..it is given correct explanation about NetBeans IDE and Maven Repositories

[Maven Repositories in NetBean IDE](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart68.html)

Comment: that requires NB 6.8, she use NB 6.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot vels and Nara. I upgraded NB to 721. Yes it has Maven in-built.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has enough resource, consider upgrading [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) to latest version 7.2. It has inbuilt maven plugin or the blow link may help you.

[How-to: Install Maven For Netbeans 6.5.x](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=FujiHowToInstallMavenForNetbeans6.5)